# unaltered citation in theorem

Tags: formatting, citing, theorems

I would like to keep the way my citations are presented to be uniform. When I enter a citation after I declare my theorem it's in italic just like the text for the theorem. Whereas the citations in the body of the text are not. I'm currently using

```
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand*{\@cite@ofmt}{\bfseries\hbox}
 \makeatother
```

to make the number in the square bracket bold.

for instance what I would like:
**Theorem 2.1** [**3**] statement

what I currently have is:
**Theorem 2.1** *[**3**] statement*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (re)define `\@cite` appropriately:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{{\normalfont[{\bfseries#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\cite{testA}
\begin{theo}
\cite{testA}
\end{theo}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testA} Author A. Title A. 2013
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the code above, both the number and the eventual note produced through the optional argument of `\cite` will be bold-faced; to have just the number, but not the note in bold-face font, you could use

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{{\normalfont[{\bfseries#1}\if@tempswa , #2\fi]}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: or, taking a cue from `\eqref` in `amsmath`, `{\textup{[{\bfseries#1...}]}}`